# How can I change the ReplyTo information in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

How can I change the ReplyTo-address and name in a marketing cloud email?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done inside of a [sender profile](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/send_classifications/).

You would [create your sender profile](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/send_classifications/create_a_sender_profile/) by following the below steps:

1. Click the Admin tab in the navigation bar.
2. Click Send Management.
3. Click Sender Profiles.
4. Click Create.
5. Complete the information in the Properties section:

   Name - Use this value to identify the sender profile in Marketing
   Cloud

   External Key - Use this value to identify the sender profile in an API call
    
   Description - Use this field to further describe the purpose of the sender profile in Marketing Cloud
6. Complete the information in the Sender Information section:

   a. Sender - Select a valid value for the From name and address associated with this sender profile:
      
    - Choose from list
      
    - Use the specified information - enter the information manually in the From Name and From Email fields

   b. From Name - enter a string or a personalization string for subscriber-specific From names, such as %%owner_name%%

   c. From Email - enter a string or a personalization string for subscriber-specific From email addresses, such as %%owner_email%%
7. Select whether to use custom settings or direct forwards in the Custom Reply Mail Management settings. Enter custom settings as necessary to determine how Reply Mail Management processes replies to your email messages.
8. Click Save.

Step 7 is where you can customize the replyto address and name.

Comment: I have already Email Reply Address configured under Email Studio -> Admin -> Account Settings -> Edit as email@email.xxx.com, but when I click on reply to an email that I sent to myself for testing I got this spammy code.

Comment: that is because it goes through SFMC reply mail managment(RMM) - that 'spammy' code is the unique ID for your send and the subscriber, to allow their RMM to properly handle the reply.  To prevent that, you need to set the sender profile to do 'direct forwards' and it will send it directly to the sending email address and skip the RMM system.

Comment: If direct forwards is selected, to which address is the email forwarded?  Where is it set?

Comment: To sender email address. Skips RMM and pushes all reply messages (including bounces, etc) to sending email.

Comment: While using Direct forwards (in sender profile), should the RMM be ON/OFF in RMM settings?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change this setting globally, you can go to *Email Studio -> Admin -> Account Settings -> Edit* and change **Email Reply Address** as well as **Email Display Name** under *General Settings*.

For further options you can configure **Reply Mail Management** under *Email Studio -> Admin -> Account Settings -> Reply Mail Management*. On this settings page you can also set the define what happens to auto-replies like out-of-office mails, etc.

If you want to configure this on a per email or group of email basis, you can configure multiple **Sender Profiles** under **Email Studio -> Admin -> Send Management -> Sender Profiles* where you can specify *Sender Information* as well as *Custom Reply Mail Management* options. These Sender Profiles can be assigned to Send Classifications.

**Further reading:**

- [Reply Mail Management](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/reply_mail_management/)
- [Enterprise Reply Mail Management](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/enterprise_reply_mail_management/)

  - [Create a Sender Profile for Use with Enterprise Reply Mail Management](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/enterprise_reply_mail_management/create_a_sender_profile_for_use_with_enterprise_reply_mail_management/)
- [Send Classifications](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/send_classifications/)

  - [Create a Sender Profile](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/send_classifications/create_a_sender_profile/)