# Reply to Alias Nam

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-studio

I'm using Custom Reply Mail Management Settings in sender profile.
When I attempt to answer to an email the reply to field fills with this line:
AliasName (reply-ff2810777c67-390_html-10915791-100004208-1@reply.email.networkdigital360.it)

Is it possible to remove the line reply-ff2810777c67-390_html-10915791-100004208-1@reply.email.networkdigital360.it and display just the alias name I set up in?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to remove your replyto address being displayed as reply-ff2810777c67-390_html-10915791-100004208-1@reply.email.networkdigital360.it is to remove RMM (Reply Mail Management) by utilizing the 'Direct Forward' option.

Beware, this means that ALL email replies, including bounces, etc. which RMM usually handles, will instead be sent to this mailbox. ALSO you lose control of having a separate replyto address, and can only have the replies sent to your sending address.

If you mean you want the email clients to not display the replyto address and only the replyto name in the reply window, this is not possible. This functionality is controlled on the Email Client level and is displayed for many purposes, including security. This way you can see that your email to 'Apple' is not actually going to Joe Bob from the Bronx.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change this setting globally, you can go to Email Studio -> Admin -> Account Settings -> Edit and change Email Reply Address as well as Email Display Name under General Settings.

For further options you can configure Reply Mail Management under Email Studio -> Admin -> Account Settings -> Reply Mail Management. On this settings page you can also set the define what happens to auto-replies like out-of-office mails, etc.

If you want to configure this on a per email or group of email basis, you can configure multiple Sender Profiles under **Email Studio -> Admin -> Send Management -> Sender Profiles* where you can specify Sender Information as well as Custom Reply Mail Management options. These Sender Profiles can be assigned to Send Classifications.

[Reply Mail Management](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/reply_mail_management/)

[How can I change the ReplyTo information in marketing cloud?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175482/how-can-i-change-the-replyto-information-in-marketing-cloud/175484)

Comment: As I said, I 've set up Custom Reply Mail Management options in sender profile, and the line I reported shows up when user reply to the email in his own mail box so I need to know if that line could be removed. I would not to display that to customers.